# Hover event stops working after sorting divs

Tags: jquery, sorting, hover

I'm working on an application which renders out images side by side. When hovering an image a hidden class is revealed showing information of the image.

I also have a sort function so that one can sort the images by points (highest first, descending) instead of the default sort (date). Both hovering and sorting works fine, except for one thing.

When the images is sorted by points and rendered out again, hovering the images doesn't work. I have looked at the generated code and it looks the same, but regardless that it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate som help here, thanks!

```
<div id="images">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="post">
            // other code here
            <div class="postDesc">
                // other code here
                <p class="postDescContent">Points: 10</p>
            </div
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="post">
            // other code here
            <div class="postDesc">
                // other code here
                <p class="postDescContent">Points: 20</p>
            </div
        </div>
    </div>
    // and so one...
</div>
```

sorting function:

```
sortByPoints: function() {
    var contents = $('div#images div[class^="image"]');

    contents.sort(function(a, b) {

        var p1= parseInt($('p.postDescContent', $(a)).text().replace('Points:','').trim()),
            p2 = parseInt($('p.postDescContent', $(b)).text().replace('Points:','').trim());
           return p1 < p2;

    });

    var images = $('#images');

    images.empty();
    images.append(contents);
}
```

hover function:

```
$('.image').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.postDesc').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.empty()` method clears all element data. You shouldn't need to empty it at all. Just do the `.append()`.

```
var images = $('#images');

//images.empty();  // remove this

images.append(contents);
```

This should be sufficient to show the reordered elements without losing any handler data.

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/mgF3L/

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()`

```
$('#images').on('hover', 'div.image', function() {
    $(this).find('.postDesc').css('color','#000');
});
```

The reason why you cannot use bind is because you append the script dynamically. Therefore, the binding is removed.

`.on()` is the replacement for `.live()`, which has been deprecated in jquery 1.7

**EDIT**
Thanks for @clive for pointing out my mistake. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5vBL/4/)

Comment: Won't work! you didn't create a delegate event at all! check my answer to see how it's being done with `on`.

Comment: _"If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound...  When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated."_

Comment: @WilliamCalvin: That's because you're doing the `sort()` before the handlers are bound. The issue is that they are sorted after, and the handlers are lost. http://jsfiddle.net/z5vBL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this with delegate event:

```
$('#images').on('hover', '.image',function () {
    $(this).find('.postDesc').toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5vBL/3/)